# How can I send a file as a parameter from controller to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip, delayed-job

From a controller, is there a way to call a method in a model with a file as a parameter, without getting an uninitialized stream error when you try to use the received file in the model?

I am trying to use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to upload files to S3 (using Paperclip). I use Heroku, so any request will time out after 30 secs, and I want to allow multiple file uploads at once.

The same problem was talked about [in the delayed_job Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/delayed_job/browse_thread/thread/f43d30f74ff056d0?fwc=2), but there was never a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to save the file locally first, or directly to S3 without going through the delayed job.  Another option would be to have the user upload directly to S3 rather than going through your stack - this approach obviously has some other issues around authentication and the ability to screen the data first, but you could handle the data screening in your delayed job instead.